# sklearn countvectroizer : results are shuffled

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, countvectorizer

here i am using countvectorizer on some text.

the result is one where counts don't match with words,

for example in index 0, "rock" should have a count of 3 instead it shows 2 and "here" has a count of 3 which "rock" should have.

what could the proplem be?

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"text" :["rock rock rock play mate here here",
                          "rock play  play here there"]})
vec = CountVectorizer()
feature = vec.fit_transform(df['text'])
b=pd.DataFrame(feature.toarray(),columns=vec.vocabulary_.keys())
print(b)
```

```
   rock  play  mate  here  there
0     2     1     1     3      0
1     1     0     2     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using *vec.vocabulary_.keys()*, use *vec.get_feature_names_out()***

I have modified your minimal reproducibility code to fix the issue.

input:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"text" :["rock rock rock play mate here here",
                          "rock play  play here there"]})
vec = CountVectorizer()
feature = vec.fit_transform(df['text'])
cols = vec.get_feature_names_out()
b=pd.DataFrame(feature.toarray(),columns=cols)
print(b)
```

output:

```
   here  mate  play  rock  there
0     2     1     1     3      0
1     1     0     2     1      1
```

You can read more on the documentation with the link:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: thank you,
I also needed to update my sk version for that to work, noticed that thanks to your link,
Thanks